# Linux RAID1, with reads restricted to one disk

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid1

I'm looking for a way to replicate a all changes on a filesystem between two disks in a master->slave setup.  One of the disks is much faster for reads, so I would like to direct all reads to this real disk for performance reasons; is it possible to do this with Linux software RAID?  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man mdadm`:

> ```
>    -W, --write-mostly
> ```
>
> subsequent  devices  listed  in  a  --build,  --create, or --add command will
>   be flagged as 'write-mostly'.  This is valid for RAID1 only and means that the 'md' driver
>   **will avoid reading from these devices if at all possible**.  **This can be useful if mirroring
>   over a slow link.**